# Flask　ユーザー情報の更新

Tags: python, html, flask

ユーザー情報の更新を行うためのページの作成を行っております。
user_maintenance.htmlでユーザーの「変更」ボタンを押した後、account.htmlへ遷移するのですが、
なぜか、ユーザー名は更新元のユーザー名が表示された状態ですが、メールアドレス部分が表示されない状態となってしまいます。（図参照）

どこが、間違っているのかが、どうしても分からない状況です。

どなたかご教示の程、よろしくお願い致します。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**app.py**

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    administrator = db.Column(db.String(1))
    post = db.relationship('BlogPost', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
 

    def __init__(self, email, username, password_hash, administrator):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = password_hash
        self.administrator = administrator


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"UserName: {self.username}"


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    # HTMLに表示するための各フィールドを作成
    email = StringField('メールアドレス', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(message='正しいメールアドレスを入力してください')])
    username = StringField('ユーザー名', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('パスワード', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('pass_confirm', message='正しいパスワードを入力してください')])
    pass_confirm = PasswordField('パスワード(確認)', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('登録')

    def validate_username(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('ユーザーは既に使われています。')

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('メールアドレスはは既に使われています。')


class UpdateUserFome(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('メールアドレス', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(message='正しいメールアドレスを入力してください')])
    username = StringField('ユーザー名', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('パスワード', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('pass_confirm', message='パスワードが一致していません')])
    pass_confirm = PasswordField('パスワード(確認)', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('更新')

    def __init__(self, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
        # 継承元のクラスを残しつつ必要な処理を行うことができる
        super(UpdateUserFome, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = user_id

@app.route('/<int:user_id>/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def account(user_id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    form = UpdateUserFome(user_id)
    # 更新処理
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # elifでフォームで取得したデーターをモデルに格納
        user.username = form.username.data
        user.email = form.email.data
        # パスワードは、フォームに入力された場合だけ更新を行うため、さらにifでフォームに入力されたか確認を行う
        if form.password.data:
            user.password_hash = form.password.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('更新されました')
        return redirect(url_for('user_maintenance'))
    # 初期表示
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        # DBから取得したユーザー名、メールをフォームに格納
        form.username.data = user.username
        form.email.date = user.email 
    return render_template('account.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**user_maintenance.html**

```html
<div class="card-header">
    <h4>最新のユーザー</h4>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ユーザー名</th>
            <th>メールアドレス</th>
            <th>管理者</th>
            <th>ブログ投稿数</th>
            <th>変更</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.administrator}}</td>
            <td><a href="#">ブログ投稿数</a></td>
            <td><a href="{{url_for('account', user_id=user.id)}}" class="btn btn-secondary">
                変更
            </a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

**account.html**

```html
<h3>ユーザー更新</h3>
<p>ユーザー情報を変更してください。</p>
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ render_field(form.username, placeholder="ユーザー名", class="form-contorol form-contorol-lg") }}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ render_field(form.email, placeholder="メールアドレス", class="form-contorol form-contorol-lg") }}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ render_field(form.password, placeholder="新パスワード", class="form-contorol form-contorol-lg") }}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ render_field(form.pass_confirm, placeholder="新パスワード(確認)", class="form-contorol form-contorol-lg") }}
    </div> 
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-light w-100", value="更新") }} 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースを読む限り、フォームのフィールドに対する受け渡しは`data`なのだと思いますが、一箇所だけ`date`になっています。

```py
@app.route('/<int:user_id>/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def account(user_id):
    ## （略）
    # 初期表示
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        # DBから取得したユーザー名、メールをフォームに格納
        form.username.data = user.username
        form.email.date = user.email  # <- 'date' へ代入している
    return render_template('account.html', form=form)
```

Comment: 有難うございます。ご指摘の通りでした。